# Generate Seletor from source code, for scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, css-selectors

I am trying to create a CSS selector from the source code of a dynamic web page. I have tried with no results with:

```
        response.css('seller-info#region *::text').get()
        response.css('seller-info > region *::text').get()
        response.css('.seller-info#region ::text').get()
        response.css('seller-info#region ::text').get()
        response.css('seller-info > region ::text').get()
        response.css('seller-info:contains("to extract")::text').get()
        response.css('.seller-info:contains("to extract")::text').get()
        response.css('.seller-info:contains("to extract") *::text').get()
        response.css('seller-info:contains("to extract") *::text').get()
```

Response of each: "None"
I need the text: "to extract"
*The region name is repeated in other code trees

**Source code**

````
<seller-info
    username='glorious'
    ispro='true'
    region="to extract"
    phoneurl='/pg/0.gif"'
    storeurl=""
    

    seniority=''
    category="1220"
    phonevisible='true'
>
   <div slot="avatar">
        
        
        
                <div class="seller-info__header--icon-container">
                    <i class="icon-yapo  icon-briefcase "></i>
                </div>
        
   </div>
</seller-info>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data from your source code that you are trying to extract - this is a tag attribute value (not tag text):

```py
region = response.css("seller-info[region]::attr(region)").get()
```

or:

```py
region = response.css("seller-info::attr(region)").get()
```

Selectors like `tagname::text` aimed to extract text between 
 opening and closing tags like `<tagname> text to extract </tagname>`

Your `<seller-info>` tag - is  self-closing tag (like `img` tag). It store data inside its attributes.